# Rotation or Reflection?

Tags: geometry, transformation, reflection

Today, I was asked to "Name and describe each transformation.  State whether or not each is an isometry."

The first one I was given was [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJrDq.png)

I am now terribly confused over whether it is a rotation or a reflection. The curved arrow suggests it is a rotation, but I suppose it could also be trying to tell me it is reflected. I am very confused, and would like to know what you guys think. Also could someone please explain to me how to know which transformation is being used, as I have several other problems that have more than one possible transformation (Or some that seem like they had multiple transformations used on them).

Any words of wisdom are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The curved arrow does not indicate anything. It is obvious that this is a reflection across a line parallel to the y-axis,namely $x=1$.

Comment: Brett, there is an interesting theorem: Any rotation or translation can be expressed as the composition of two reflections. Your confusion could came unconsciously from this, perhaps? Also, it allows you to *hack* it, just say that any of them is a maximum of $2$ reflections!

Comment: A very useful advice: Define rotation and reflection using vectors and do the calculations. Each calculation must do only one isometry, so if you can input initial values in the definitions and make them have the same coordinates of the other object (it becames a system of equations and It's kinda easy to see if there is a solution).

Answer (score 1):

There is no rotation mapping the quadrilateral $ABCD$ to $EFGH$. Indeed such a rotation would have to map $B$ to $F$ and $A$ to $G$ to preserve angles, but then the rest of the quadrilateral would end up above the line $FG$ instead of below it. On the other hand there is a reflection (about the line $x=1$) which does it.

Having said that, the question is ambiguous because the following affine transformation also maps $ABCD$ to $EFGH$:
$$
  (x,y)\mapsto(2-x,11/3+2x/3-y).
$$

Answer (score 0):

The curved arrow simply means the picture on the left has become this after a change(rotation or reflection.)

Imagine that  the shape (a trapezium here) is a piece of wood placed on a table. And you are viewing it from directly above the table.   Rotation can be carried out without lifting it off the table. Reflection means you lift it off flip it and place it back.

Now comparing both the pictures you can decide which transformation was carried out?